# Leaflet layer control style

Tags: leaflet

I have trouble with changing the image in layer control
I tried this: https://jsfiddle.net/v95h1kx4/

My browser has no problem with this but some people have top of the control blue and bottom of the control white - without the actual image. The weird thing is that they even use the same browser (Firefox, Chrome). It shows no errors for them too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `background-size: 20px 20px;` in `.leaflet-control-layers-toggle` CSS.

Updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v95h1kx4/5/